# Dynamically added <input> not being rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a string which holds a form that I want to dynamically render.

When the user clicks "Add Step", my template string is added to a list and rendered with an `ngFor`. The problem is that the input doesn't render, only the `<h3>` tag.

Before button click:

[image]

After - no input is rendered on screen or in the html:

[image]

ts:

```
scenarioTemplate = `
  <div id="content">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <input name="{{i}}" [ngModel]="i">
  </div>`;

steps = [];

addScenarioStep() {
    this.steps.push(this.scenarioTemplate);
}
```

html:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <fieldset ngModelGroup="inputs" #inputs="ngModelGroup">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index">
      <div [innerHTML]=step attr.stepId="{{i}}"></div>
    </ng-container>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="addStepBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="addScenarioStep()">Add Scenario Step +</button>
```

Comment: The Angular syntax `{{i}}` and `[ngModel]` will not be honored when rendered with `[innerHTML]` binding. Is there a reason to insert the template with `[innerHTML]` instead of puting that markup in the component template? By the way, you may prefer this binding syntax for the attribute: `[attr.stepId]="i"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Your comment could be answer. This seems to be XY question - just wrong tool for a job

Answer (score 0):

1. Put that whole thing

```
  <div id="content">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <input name="{{i}}" [ngModel]="i">
  </div>
```

in the template, not the TS.

2. Don't mutate the array. Instead of

```
this.steps.push(newElem);
```

do

```
this.steps = [...this.steps, newElem];
```

Comment: I need to add new form elements at run-time, I can't do that if I don't modify the array

Comment: `this.steps = [...this.steps, newElem]` creates a new array with old and new elements included, and it triggers change detection, while mutating the array doesn't.

Comment: Ah sorry - I misunderstood, will try shortly